# Do USB keyboards have hardware auto-repeat? (like PS/2 keyboards)

Tags: usb, keyboard, operating-systems

Or is auto-repeat done in software on the computer that the keyboard is connected to?

Answer (score 2):

I'm reverse-engineering the USB keyboard interface protocol (packets exchanged through the USB interface) using a USB sniffer. As far as I see, a key is not repeated from a USB keyboard. This means that keyboard repeat is done on the PC side, probably software that deal with [USB HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) (USB driver?).

I'm not familiar with OS low-level software, so that I cannot pinpoint where the repeat is done. From an application, you cannot tell if it is done by the keyboard (PS/2 keyboard) or is done by software (USB).

This actually does make sense. Most USB keyboards uses USB low speed and fetching a key is done by polling (a USB keyboard cannot send a new keycode by itself). If keyboard repeat is done within the USB keyboard, the repeat would be not smooth.

I'm trying to confirm this with USB specifications, but so far I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard refresh rate can be BIOS set but more importantly for you via Windows-> Control Panel -> Human Interface Devices (or) Keyboard / Mouse (or) A widget from your keyboard maker.  Here you can set the controls for "delay before repeat", repeat rate" and "cursor blink rate"

Hope this helps!

Freaky Boy

Comment: I know where to set it in my OS. I just don't know if the setting is influencing the keyboard driver or directly the keyboard hardware. With PS/2 keyboards, as far as I know, repeat rate is sent via PS/2 commands to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is a combination of both.

A keyboard doesn't have to implement it in hardware and any modern OS will apply its own rate-limiter on it regardless of what the keyboard does. The OS sort of "has to do it", because there are all sorts of keyboard with their own weird variants.

Doing it in the OS makes sure the user-experience is consistent.